# CSS3 rotate div but keep background without rotation

Tags: css, rotation

Is there a way to use transform rotate a div but keep the background from rotating with it? if not is there another solution with a jQuery or something?

Answer (score 3):

u can try this

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="yourelement"></div>
</div>
```

and this style

```
        #container{
            position: absolute;
            top:100px;
            left:100px;
            transform: rotate(30deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        #yourelement{
            position: absolute;
            top:-100px;
            left:-50px;
            transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
            background-image:url(../img/bg.jpg);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add an outside wrapper with the background and rotate the inner element instead.

Comment: and apply an overflow:hidden to hide the background that keeps showing? and do you think it would still be possible to hover the bg?

Comment: i think you should post a fiddle in which you exactly explain what you have to do

Answer (score 0):

Try using 2 div blocks and overlay the div with rotating content over the fixed background div. Make overlay transparent. Hope it helps.